# How to make custom button of MessageDialog not to close dialog when clicked, in RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an RCP Application where upen delete, MessageDialog is used for confirming the delete operation. One of the button as you can see in the code below, is a "preview" button, where if clicked, another dialog will popup to display more info about the intended operation consequences. This "preview" button is closing my main MessageDialog one by default somehow.. What should I do to make it not close the main dialog?

```
MessageDialog dialog =
         new MessageDialog(null, "Dangerous Activity", null,
                    "Are you sure you want to delete?", MessageDialog.CONFIRM,
                    new String[]{"Preview>", "Delete", "Cancel"}, 0);

     int dialogResult = dialog.open();
     // if preview button is selected
      if (dialogResult == 0) {
           // open another dialog for a second more informative warning
           // but DO NOT CLOSE THE CURRENT MAIN ONE..HOW TO?

            }
```

I appreciate any help!

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding the buttonPressed method on MessageDialog:

```
MessageDialog dialog =
     new MessageDialog(null, "Dangerous Activity", null,
                "Are you sure you want to delete?", MessageDialog.CONFIRM,
                new String[]{"Preview>", "Delete", "Cancel"}, 0)
{
protected void buttonPressed(int buttonId) {
    setReturnCode(buttonId);
    // close(); Call close for Delete or Cancel?
}};
```

Comment: wow. thanks for your answer!! May I ask please about the buttonId? based on my/your code above, there are button labels. In this specific example, how can someone create or specify the buttonIds? because "preview","delete","cancel" here are button labels,right?

Comment: I am sorry hehe.. I used 0,1,2 and it worked for the Ids.. not so smart comment it was..
Thanks again for the whole answer!